# Matrix multiplication using pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to do matrix multiplication using pthreads and creating one thread for each computation of each row instead of each element. Suppose there are two matrices 
A[M][K],B[K][N] . Where am I going wrong ?

```
int A[M][K];
int B[K][N];
int C[][];

void *runner (void *param);


struct v
{
int i;
 int j;
};

pthread_t tid[M];

for (i = 0; i < M; i++) // It should create M threads 
{
    struct v *data = (struct v *) malloc (sizeof (struct v));
    data->i = i;
    data->j = j;
    pthread_create (&tid[count], &attr, runner, data);
    pthread_join (tid[count], NULL);
    count++;
}

runner (void *param) //
{
    struct v *test;
    int t = 0;
    test = (struct v *) param;

    for (t = 0; t < K; t++)  // I want to compute it for a row instead of an element 
    {
        C[test->i][test->j] = C[test->i][test->j] + A[test->i][t] * B[t][test->j];
    }
    pthread_exit (0);
}
```

Comment: Beyond the fact that thread creation and destruction and sync will kill all performance gains here and more?  :)

Comment: For the record, is this homework? If it's not, it'd be far more efficient to use inline assembly for the platform in use. As @MichaelDorgan above notes - the thread overhead is far greater than the actual computations in all likelihood. What's wrong with your code so far? Does it run/crash/segfault, or just give a bad answer? Can you give us a couple sample runs?

Comment: BTW, where is j, struct v, K, etc. defined above?  You've cut and paste not quite enough code for us to fully see what is going on here.  Having just a for loop with cryptically named vars doesn't help us understand what is going on.  More code plz.

Comment: I have done that . It was for creating thread for each element earlier now I am modifying it to thread to compute each row of resultant matrix . Earlier I was running loop for both rows and columns in thread creation block and now I am just running one loop of rows but I am confused how should I modify the below loop as one thread computes one row of resultant matrix

Comment: If you already have a thread pool setup waiting for work assignment, you may get a performance bump, the likelihood increasing as the matrix size does. But as-written you'll quickly find (perhaps not so quickly) that the setup/teardown of your threads is not going to be cheap.

Comment: In C, don't cast `void*`, in particular the return of `malloc`. Most often casts in C indicate that you are doing something wrong. Generally speaken, your code looks as if you are quite a beginner in C. Try programming simpler things first. Augment the warning level of your compiler. After some weeks of programming experience you then should go to threads.

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of data->j. If you are computing entire rows the row index is the only thing your thread needs. Right now your runner(..) computes a single element. You have to iterate over all row elements computing them one by one.
Second, do not join a thread right after it is created. This way you have only one thread running at a time. Start joining threads when all threads have been created.