# Matrix multiplication in C using pthreads, possible array access issue

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix

Edited to reflect correction in comments, thank you Ben.

I have looked at [Pthreads matrix multiplication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974499/pthreads-matrix-multiplication-error), [Dynamic Matrix Multiplication with Pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061571/dynamic-matrix-multiplication-with-pthreads), and [Matrix multiplication using pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881046/matrix-multiplication-using-pthreads) but none seemed to address the issue I'm having. I am attempting to adapt the following serial version of a matrix multiplier (the kij method) to a threaded version using pthreads. Both deal solely with square matrices of size N * N; matmul takes N as an argument at runtime, matmul_threaded takes N and t, where t is the number of threads desired. Here is matmul.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void initmat(double *,long);
void kij(double *a, double *b, double *c, long N);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   double *a,*b,*c;
   long N = atol(argv[1]);

   // Allocate N-by-N matrix in the heap.
   a = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
   b = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
   c = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));

   // Initialize the matrix.
   initmat(a,N);
   initmat(b,N);
   kij(a,b,c,N);
}

void initmat(double *mat, long N) {
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
     mat[i*N+j] = i + j;
}

void kij(double *a, double *b, double *c, long N) {
   double r;
   int i, j, k;
   for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        r = a[N*i+k];
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        c[N*i+j] += r*b[N*k+j];
    }
}
```

This works as expected up to N = 1000. (my edge case for this exercise) My strategy with matmul_threaded was to split the k dimension up over t many threads, then iterate over i and j as usual, and include pointers to the arrays in each thread package. matmul_threaded works correctly up to N = 129. For the values I've tested greater than 129, (130...140, 200, 300, 500, 999, 1000) it seg faults.

I am almost certain that I am accessing the arrays incorrectly, but I cannot for the life of me spot where. Here is matmul_threaded.c:

```
// matmul_threaded.c

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int tid;
   long N, nInt;
   long *a, *b, *c;
} PKG;

void *kij(void *pkg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   long *a, *b, *c;
   int thread_count,p,q,tid;  
   long N = atol(argv[1]);  // moved here from below mallocs, solved
   pthread_t *thread; 
   PKG *package;

   a = (long *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(long));
   b = (long *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(long));
   c = (long *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(long));
   for (p = 0; p < N; p++)
        for (q = 0; q < N; q++)
        {
            a[N*p+q] = p + q;
            b[N*p+q] = p + q;
        } 
   thread_count = atoi(argv[2]);  
   thread = (pthread_t *) malloc (thread_count*sizeof(pthread_t)); 
   package = (PKG *) malloc(thread_count*sizeof(PKG));

   for (tid = 0; tid < thread_count; tid++) {
      package[tid].tid = tid;
      package[tid].N = N;
      package[tid].nInt = N/thread_count;
      package[tid].a = a;
      package[tid].b = b;
      package[tid].c = c;
      pthread_create(&thread[tid], NULL, kij, (void *) &package[tid]);
   }

   for (tid = 0; tid < thread_count; tid++) {
      pthread_join(thread[tid], NULL); 
   }

    free(thread);

    return 0;
}   

void *kij(void *pkg) {
    PKG *mypkg = (PKG *) pkg;
    long i,j,k,r,n = mypkg->N;
    for(k = (mypkg->tid)*(mypkg->nInt)+1; k <= (mypkg->tid + 1)*(mypkg->nInt); k++) {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            r = mypkg->a[n*i+k];
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                mypkg->c[n*i+j] += r * mypkg->b[n*k+j];
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Hopefully I have been specific and clear enough, and thank you in advance for your time! Edit: to clarify, this doesn't print/return anything because it doesn't need to; executing it using the "time" command is sufficient, as we're just comparing the time to completion.

Comment: You're using N before you initialize it.

Comment: Oh, I'm so embarrassed. That was it, exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're using N before you initialize it. – Ben